# How to write a C api program to make calls using linphone sdk

Tags: c, linphone

I am very new for the C programming, I want to create a C program to make calls using linphone-sdk. i don't know how to start writing a C program.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the corresponding development package named [liblinphone-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/liblinphone-dev).

Another good method is to download LinPhone [source code package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/linphone) and then read it.

To start hacking you have to do the following:

1. Enable Source Code repositories in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. Install build-dependencies by

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep linphone
   ```
3. Download source code package and compile it without modifications

   ```
   apt-get source -b linphone
   ```
4. Examine the downloaded source codes

Next step to read is GitHub repositories at https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications .